# Не извлекается аудио из видео файла

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
extern "C"
{
    #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
    #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
    #include <libswscale/swscale.h>
}

#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    AVFormatContext *formatContext = NULL;
    AVCodecContext *video_codec_context = NULL, *audio_codec_context = NULL;
    AVCodec *video_codec = NULL, *audio_codec = NULL;
    AVFrame *frame = NULL;
    AVPacket packet;
    int video_stream = -1, audio_stream = -1;
    uint8_t *buffer = NULL;
    int frameFinished = 0;

    av_register_all();
    if (avformat_open_input(&formatContext, "in\\1.mp4", NULL, NULL) != 0)
        return -1;
    if (avformat_find_stream_info(formatContext, NULL) < 0)
        return -1;
    av_dump_format(formatContext, 0, "in\\1.mp4", 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < formatContext->nb_streams; i++)
    {
        if (formatContext->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO && video_stream == -1)
            video_stream = i;
        if (formatContext->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO && audio_stream == -1)
            audio_stream = i;
    }

    if (video_stream == -1 || audio_stream == -1)
        return -1;

    video_codec_context = formatContext->streams[video_stream]->codec;
    audio_codec_context = formatContext->streams[audio_stream]->codec;

    video_codec = avcodec_find_decoder(video_codec_context->codec_id);
    if (video_codec == NULL)
        return -1;

    audio_codec = avcodec_find_decoder(audio_codec_context->codec_id);
    if (audio_codec == NULL)
        return -1;

    if (avcodec_open2(video_codec_context, video_codec, NULL) < 0)
        return -1;
    if (avcodec_open2(audio_codec_context, audio_codec, NULL) < 0)
        return -1;

    frame = av_frame_alloc();

    while (av_read_frame(formatContext, &packet) >= 0) {
        frameFinished = 0;
        if (packet.stream_index == audio_stream) {
            avcodec_decode_audio4(audio_codec_context, frame, &frameFinished, &packet);

            if (frameFinished) {
                int data_size = av_samples_get_buffer_size(NULL, audio_codec_context->channels,
                    frame->nb_samples,
                    audio_codec_context->sample_fmt,
                    1);
                buffer = frame->data[0];
            }
        }

        av_free_packet(&packet);
    }

    av_free(frame);
    avcodec_close(video_codec_context);
    avcodec_close(audio_codec_context);
    avformat_close_input(&formatContext);
    getchar();
    return 0;
 }
```

Пытаюсь извлечь данные из аудио кадра, но data_size = -22, а данные кадра пустые.

Comment: Может этот пример поможет: https://github.com/UnickSoft/FFMpeg-decode-example Там правда кадры извлекаются, но есть заглушка кажется для аудио.

Answer (score 0):

-22 это `EINVAL`, то бишь один из параметров, передаваемых в функцию, имеет неправильное значение. Возможно это происходит из-за использования устаревшего поля `AVStream::codec`. Вместо него следует использовать `AVStream::codecpar` и собирать с `FF_API_LAVF_AVCTX 0`.

Comment: codecpar = NULL

Comment: @Totaku Это странно. А при сборке libav нужный аудио кодек был включен?

Comment: Я не собирал libav... Я подключил avcodec.lib
avdevice.lib
avfilter.lib
avformat.lib
avutil.lib
swscale.lib

Comment: @Totaku А ну тогда указывать `FF_API_LAVF_AVCTX` не следует.

Comment: Я убрал #define FF_API_LAVF_AVCTX 0, но codecpar остался равным NULL.

Comment: @Totaku А в полях `audio_codec_context->channels` `frame->nb_samples` `audio_codec_context->sample_fmt` адекватные значения?

Comment: audio_codec_context->channels = 0, frame->nb_samples = 1024, audio_codec_context->sample_fmt = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_U8. Это вариант без codecpar.